# MinGW can't find glfw3.h

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, glfw

Ello,

I have been struggling with this problem for some time now, and after much searching, trial, and error, I come here. I want to use GLFW for a project, so I made a simple `main.cpp` file. In it, is the code

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {


    return 0;


}
```

Simple enough. just to test if it is included is all.

However, when I try to compile this code in MinGW, I get the error:

```
main.cpp:1: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
```

In the project folder are the files `main.cpp` , `glfw3.dll`, and the folder named `GLFW` that contains the files `glfw3.h` and `glfw3native.h`.

the `GLFW` folder is also inside the MinGW include folder, and both `libglfw3.a` and `libglfw3dll.a` are present inside the MinGW lib folder.

Text Editor: Notepad++

OS: Windows 8 64-bit

Compiler: MinGW32 4.8.1

I figured the problem may lie in me using the 32-bit version of GLFW, but I planned on the project being 32-bit anyway. I don't know whether MinGW is 32 or 64 bit.

Please help.

Comment: try #include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

Comment: I did what you said, but now the compiler is telling me both `stdint.h` and `GL/gl.h` are missing. These are coming from the `glfw3.h` file, however.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem.

Turns out, I didn't have C-make, nor GnuWin32. Apparently, these were needed for non-Visual Studio compiling. Along with the suggestion Rishikesh made, and after I added the programs into both the System, and User, Environment Variables, I'm now able to compile properly. Thanks for you all's help!